# c++ operator overloading (v << 1,2,3;)?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Take a look at this syntax :

```
Matrix<int , 3 , 3 > m;
m << 1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6,
     7, 8, 9;
std::cout << m;
```

The output:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How can i overload first << operator like this ?

Comment: I'd rather go for `m = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`.

Comment: you mean c++11 (initializer_list) feature ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/

Comment: You'd overload operators `,` *and* `<<`. But it would still not account for operator precedence

Comment: @StoryTeller, Actually, it would. `operator<<` returns a proxy object that overloads `operator,`. It's similar to Boost.Assign's `cont += 1, 3, 5;`.

Comment: @chris, yeah a proxy object would complete the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may help you : https://ideone.com/Ap6WWt

```
template <typename T, int W, int H>
class MatrixStream
{
public:
    MatrixStream(Matrix<T, W, H>& mat, const T& value) : mat(mat), index(0)
    {
        *this, value;
    }

    MatrixStream& operator , (const T& value);
private:
    Matrix<T, W, H>& mat;
    int index;
};

template <typename T, int W, int H>
class Matrix
{
public:
    MatrixStream<T, W, H> operator << (const T& value) {
        return MatrixStream<T, W, H>(*this, value);
    }

    T m[W][H];
};

template <typename T, int W, int H>
MatrixStream<T, W, H>& MatrixStream<T, W, H>::operator , (const T& value)
{
    assert(index < W * H);
    int w = index / H;
    int h = index % H;
    mat.m[w][h] = value;
    ++index;
    return *this;
}
```

but overloading `operator ,` is highly discouraged.
As said in the comment, you may use as alternative `m << {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`
or `m << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5 << 6 << 7 << 8 << 9`. (the first one is cleaner IMHO).

Comment: better not to overload `,` for the base matrix object. Better use `<<`. That might easily get nasty...

Comment: @Deduplicator: I agree, but OP has chosen this syntax :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 Actually, this syntax was chosen long ago by [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) (check "comma-initialization").

Comment: I wonder how we could make this to work in one line. Like Matrix<int, 3 , 3> m << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;

Comment: @Veritas: with `Matrix(std::initilizer_list<T>)` You may do `Matrix<int, 3 , 3> m = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};`

Comment: I am aware of that. I was wondering if it would be possible to do the same with the no curly braces syntax that the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an expression such as :

```
CleanInitArray a(6);
a = 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

It is read by the compiler like this:

```
((((((a=1),2),3),4),5),6);
```

Therefore you need to overload the assignment operator to return an array-like object and use that to overload the comma operator,.

Comment: Are you sure that is not more like `a = (((((1, 2), 3), 4), 5), 6)`?

Comment: i just tested **int a;
 a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
 cout << a << endl;** and the output was `1` .

Comment: @Deduplicator, we can be sure http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @amin, the output fits the operator precedence. There is only one assignment happening, and it's the first.

Answer (score 1):

The only useful application of overloading `operator,` I've ever seen in my whole C++ life was [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html), and even this has become redundant in C++11, thanks to `std::initializer_list`.

Nevertheless, it cannot hurt to know how it works, so I suggest you just look at the Boost source code. It's open source, you can download it for free, and it's known to work as intended.

Comment: I've used syntax `(3,_,8)` to mean something like `std::vector{3,4,5,6,7,8}`, or like `(3:8)` in Matlab (only it doesn't really store all numbers, like [`std::slice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice)). When indexing an array with this kind of *range*, no parentheses are needed: `a[3,_,8]`. It has been extremely convenient to me.